I want to call a c# .dll file from rust code
Calling a C# .dll from Rust: Issue with Function Invocation
Problem:
I'm attempting to call functions from a C# .dll in Rust using the libloading crate. While one function (my_name) works correctly, another function (start_monitor) fails with an error related to a missing dependency.
C# Code (MicMonitorDllNetFramework):
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi; using NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces; using RGiesecke.DllExport; using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MicMonitorDllNetFramework {
public class MicMonitor
{                  
    [DllExport("start_monitor", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static void GetActiveApplications()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Under the start monitor...");
        var activeApps = new List<string>();
        using (var deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            var devices = deviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                var sessionManager = device.AudioSessionManager;
                var sessions = sessionManager.Sessions;
                for (int i = 0; i < sessions.Count; i++)
                {
                    var session = sessions[i];
                    string appName = "Unknown application";
                    try
                    {
                        if (session.State != AudioSessionState.AudioSessionStateInactive)
                        {
                            var processId = session.GetProcessID;
                            var process = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId);
                            appName = process.ProcessName;
                            activeApps.Add(appName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Log or handle the error if needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var app in activeApps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(app);
        }          
    }

    [DllExport("my_name", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static void MyName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}}

Rust Code (main.rs):
extern crate libloading;

use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

type SayHelloFunc = unsafe extern "C" fn();

fn main() { let lib_path = "C:\path\to\MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll"; let lib = unsafe { Library::new(lib_path).expect("Could not load the library") };
unsafe {
    let myname: Symbol<SayHelloFunc> = lib.get(b"my_name\0").expect("Could not load the function good_morning");
    let mics: Symbol<SayHelloFunc> = lib.get(b"start_monitor\0").expect("Could not load the function start_monitor");

    myname();
    mics(); // This call fails
}

}
Error Message:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NAudio.Wasapi, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e279aa5131008a41' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at MicMonitorDllNetFramework.MicMonitor.GetActiveApplications()
error: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\rust_mergedDll.exe (exit code: 0xe0434352)
Additional Details:
The my_name function successfully prints "Hello world!".
The start_monitor function fails with a FileNotFoundException, specifically for NAudio.Wasapi.
I've verified that NAudio.Wasapi is referenced correctly in the C# project and is available in the same directory as the DLL.
and when I'm calling the DLL(both function) from a c# console application is work fine .
What I've Tried:
Dependency Verification: I've verified that NAudio.Wasapi is correctly referenced in the C# project and is present in the same directory as MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll.
Function Invocation: I successfully invoked the my_name function from Rust using the libloading crate.
Error Identification: When attempting to invoke the start_monitor function from Rust, I encountered a FileNotFoundException related to NAudio.Wasapi.
Expectation:
I expected that both functions (my_name and start_monitor) would behave similarly, given that they are exported from the same C# DLL (MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll).
Steps Taken:
I loaded the C# DLL (MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll) using the libloading crate in Rust.
I successfully obtained and invoked the my_name function from Rust, confirming that basic function invocation works.
Issue Encountered:
FileNotFoundException: The start_monitor function fails to execute and throws a FileNotFoundException specifically for NAudio.Wasapi.
Question:
How can I resolve the FileNotFoundException when calling the start_monitor function from Rust? Despite NAudio.Wasapi being present in the same directory as MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll, it seems to be missing at runtime.
Additional Details:
I am primarily a C# developer and new to Rust, so detailed explanations or step-by-step solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Tags: [c#], [rust], [dll], [libloading], [naudio]
Dependencies: libloading = "0.7"

Hmm... Just for the sake of the attempt, try putting the dependency dll in the current working directory.

@ChayimFriedman Thank you for your suggestion. I tried placing the dependency DLL in the current working directory, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Since I'm new to Rust, could you please provide a more detailed solution or any other suggestions? I appreciate your help. Thank you again!

As far as I can tell, your Rust code is flawless. The problem is in your C# code, or in the library providing [DllExport].

Does this help? https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/226

NAudio.Wasapi references NAudio.Core:
<ProjectReference Include="..\NAudio.Core\NAudio.Core.csproj" />

https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio.Wasapi/NAudio.Wasapi.csproj
Ensure that the NAudio.Core dll is in the same directory as MicMonitorDllNetFramework.dll along with the Nudio.Wasapi dll.
